How to model a wind turbine with a converter in Simulink?
I am currently working on modeling a wind energy system with a DC-AC converter in Simulink for my research project. I am having trouble finding the necessary equations for the modeling, specifically those governing the conversion of wind energy into electrical energy and the regulation of the converter.
The system should include a wind turbine model with either a direct-drive or induction generator, and a converter to connect the generator to the grid. I am looking for resources or examples on how to represent this in Simulink, as well as the equations to use for the turbine dynamics and converter control.
If anyone has experience modeling such a system or knows the basic equations for these components, it would be really helpful for me. I want to know how they derived these two equations in detail.

So, how do you calculate the energy available in the wind? What is the max you can extract from that available power?

"I want to know how they derived...".  Who's "they"? Please edit your question to cite your sources.

While you're editing your question, give more detail on what you're modeling and why -- models need to be right-sized for the problem at hand.  Are you modeling the behavior of one modest turbine attached to a reliable dumb grid?  Are you modeling the behavior of an isolated turbine attached to a smart grid?  Are you modeling the behavior of 10,000 turbines going through their own substation?  Etc. -- each of these scenarios (and what you want to find out from them) will require a different model.

Detailed models of turbines can include modeling airfoils, integrating or at least approximating the forces from the airfoil of each cross section of the turbine in wind conditions to produce torque values. A tool like xfoil can simplify this part. Someone may also have a more friendly version for simulink, but you can always have simulink approximate these from tables.
3 is also the magic number for number of blades. If you complete this model, you will see why via power calculations, testing different turbine geometry.
Even at steady wind, the aerodynamic conditions at the blades also depend on the RPM of the turbine (since wind relative to the blade is what matters for applying coefficients of lift and drag). RPM will undoubtedly be a state for your model. Wind speeds and variations over area might be inputs to drive this part of the model. (You can get wind data from some weather stations online to tie it to reality).
Once you have torque, one can use a generator's torque/power/voltage/etc curves. Note that your generator and its load affects your RPM  as well, so yet another model input. (You might consider power usage data or some fraction thereof to tie it to reality, or pick what load your generator drives, possibly in some controlled manner where you try to achieve ideal RPM for your blade geometry.)
To be thorough, you'll have to model deformation of turbine blades under wind and rpm loads, and switch airfoil calculations accordingly. The mechanical deformations become more states. It is important to include this (even if you only consider beam bending) when designing a turbine blade since it drives size of blade as a function of distance from the hub. If you already have a geometry, you can instead use the representation of that geometry as it is loaded.
